# Creating a TAR file using JTar library

Tags: java, compression, zip, tar, apache-commons

I have been trying to create a tar file from JAVA using the JTar library.I am trying to pack two files into one tar file.However the second file doesn't get listed in the created tar.Rather it is showing up as the content of the first file.

My code looks like :

```
    // Output file stream
    FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream("C:\\tarFile");

    // Create a TarOutputStream
    TarOutputStream out = new TarOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest));

    // Files to tar
    File[] filesToTar = new File[2];
    filesToTar[0] = new File("C:\\tarSample\\File1.txt");
    filesToTar[1] = new File("C:\\tarSample\\File2.txt");

    for (File f : filesToTar)
    {
        TarEntry entry = new TarEntry(f);

        out.putNextEntry(entry);
        BufferedInputStream origin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));

        int count;
        byte data[] = new byte[2048];
        while ((count = origin.read(data)) != -1)
        {
            out.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        out.flush();
        origin.close();
    }

    out.close();
    dest.close();
```

When i open the contents of the tarFile using "cat" command it looks like :

tarSample/File1.txt100644      0      0          10 12301634500  13305 0ustarkumarang     0      0 tarSample/File2.txt100644      0      0           7 12301634511  13276 0ustarkumarang     0      0

If my understanding is correct the tarEntry is getting added to the tar file .However the contents of the files are not getting written.

Any body knows a fix ?

Thanks.

Comment: what does `tar -tvf C:\\tarFile` show you ?

Comment: It just shows the details of File1. When I extract the tar and open up the File1 , it is having File2's name as its content.

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to

```
FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream("C:\\tarFile.tar");
```